# How to make form text field to accept $ symbol and commas in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails form which contains a field where the user can enter a currency value as shown below:

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :amount %>
      <br/>
      <%= f.text_field :amount %>
    </div>
```

Currently if a user copies a currency value (say $10,000.50) from a label and pastes it into this text field, it gives an error saying only numbers are allowed.

How to make the text field accept $ symbols and commas but while submitting, only the numbers should be considered.

Comment: usually text field excepts everything you type, check if you have some validation on amount field in your model

Comment: what is data type of amount field? if its decimal or integer make it string. then it will accept everything.